# Smart contact audit using JS, issue with uint8 data type

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js, audit

I'm trying to test the creating contact for overflows,
in solidity code variable `desiredDecimals` is `uint8`

**JS tests:**

When I pass 2^8 in .js

```
it("fail test overflow desiredDecimals uint8 contract creating", async function() {
    let desiredDecimals = 2**8
    let token = await Token.new("Test token", desiredDecimals);
})
```

there is no error and the contact is created,  `desiredDecimals = 0`

**Solidity tests:**

Writing the same test on Solidity,

```
function desiredDecimalsOverflow() public {
    uint8 desiredDecimals = 2**8;
    new Token("Test token", desiredDecimals);
}
```

the contact wasn't created, and tests are failed, which is correct.

I suppose that some issue with data types between js and Solidity happens,
but I can't reveal the exact issue.

Comment: Presumably with the latter you get a compile-time error like "`256` is not implicitly convertible to `uint8`"? With the former, there's no such error. (The Solidity code is valid, and the JavaScript you're running just passes in a 0.)